# What counts as a Login for Salesforce?

Tags: login, login-history

My users don't actually log in multiple times in a day, yet the login report shows many - one user has approx 8 logins per hour, but I know he doesn't actually 'log in' that many times. Does opening a Salesforce page in a new tab count as a login? That seems to be what it's doing, but I'd just like to confirm.

As Admin I log in generally once a day, but have multiple tabs running at the same time for various areas - yet my supposed 'Log in' count is also very high.

Update 17/09: I discovered that it was logging my Dataloader use as a login as well, and on top of that it records it as an IE11 login, even though I'm using Chrome. Our OAuth logins (for Lightning Sync) occur multiple times a days, so excluding those will give a more accurate count, yet I still can't seem to record only actual browser logins.

Comment: Are your users perchance using an email integration like Salesforce for Outlook or Cirrus Insight? Or a similar always-on integration?

Comment: Yes, we have Lightning Sync for Outlook running, but I check on the login Client Type and filter on 'Browser' to exclude that, yet there are still multiple logins.